# Multiple object sets are not supported. object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of ApplicationUser when creating roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

i have been working with ASP.NET identity 2.0, same code was running well before, but later on it got stuck and getting error as: [image]

```
"Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets  'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'TestProject.DataManagerWebUI.Models.ApplicationUser'. " in Startup.cs method.
```

i added a function to create default roles and it had been executing well without error, now getting this error.
following is my code:

```
      public partial class Startup
      {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandDefaultUsers();
       }
    // In this method we will create default User roles and Super Admin user for login
    private void createRolesandDefaultUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        // In Startup creating first Super Admin Role and creating a default Super Admin User
        **if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Super Admin"))** //getting error at this line.
        {
```

Comment: when i tried to get all Application users in my code, it automatically created following property in ApplicationDbContext class: public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<IHM_Cloud_ERP.DataInputManagerWebUI.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }. (i removed this line and now everything is fine.)

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and mark it as the solution :)

Comment: ok @JamesP, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i tried to get all Application users in my code, it automatically created following property in ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Project.DataInputManagerWebUI.Models.ApplicationU‌​ser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }.
```

(i removed this line and now everything is fine.)